# AngularJS CSS animation - animate two elements same time

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJs specifically angular-animate. I have in the html a toggle which currently transitions the div class "my-first-animation". How do I apply a transition to the background at same time?
That is I would like the background-color of the body to fade from white to black when the div class "my-first-animation" appears. Thanks in advance. UPDATE: K.Torres answered work really well.Thank you. However I tried adding the following dark-bg transitions to the CSS but it does not seem to work. Any one no why? Thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title> Applying Animations</title>
        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
            app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope){
                $scope.on = false;
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            /*start*/
            .my-first-animation.ng-enter{
                transition: .5s all;
                opacity: 0;
            }
                .my-first-animation.ng-enter-active{
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .my-first-animation.ng-leave{
                transition: .5s all;
                opacity: 1;
            }
                .my-first-animation.ng-leave-active{
                opacity: 0;
            }



     .dark-bg.ng-add {
        transition: .5s all;
       background:white;

     }
     .dark-bg.ng-add-active {
       background:gray;

     }
    .dark-bg.ng-remove {
       transition: .5s all;
       background:gray;

     }
     .dark-bg.ng-remove-active {
       background:white;

     }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="homeCtrl" ng-class="{ 'dark-bg': on }">
     <button ng-click="on=!on">Toggle Content</button>
     <div class="my-first-animation" ng-if="on">
            This content will fade in over a half second. 
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ng-class` on `<body>` tag, here is the documentation for [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-class="{ 'dark-bg': on }" >
```

this will add css class `dark-bg` to the `<body>` tag  when `on` variable is true,

when u click on the button `on` variable will toggle between `true` & `false`, and `ng-class` is depend on `on` variable too, so if `on` is `true` `body` will get `dark-bg` css class, if `on` is `false` then `dark-bg` css class will remove from the `body`.

so then you can add

```
.dark-bg {
   background:gray;
   transition: .5s all;
 }
```

here is the [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KWMRgeKl7bxZ8qQA1SIg?p=preview)

Comment: Brilliant! That work's a treat. Thank you very much. Further question, I tried using the following CSS but it didn't work (updated in the original question). That is I used the add/remove events for ng-class in the CSS. Appreciate any comments thanks again.